# Ιnput referred noise of an amplifier

Tags: amplifier, noise, noise-spectral-density, low-noise-amplifier

I have a problem with a low noise amplifier because I can't find in ADS(Advance design system) software how to integrating under the are of a measured curve in a specific frequency range.Can someone help me how I can achieve that?

Figure 1 shows a paper result and how the noise measured and Figure 2,3 shows my results.As we can see the measured values for the noise is approximately the same but I would like to integrate under the are of a measured curve from 10Hz to 98kHz to find the total input referred noise and I don't know how I can do it.Also, I had searched a lot on the internet and I didn't find something useful.Can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per your final table, 1Hz has 7.48e-5 noise voltage. And 1MHz has 6.55e-11. A fine V = 1/F curve. This is not Power = 1/Frequency, the expected 1/F behavior.

Given V = 1/F, this is the power of an integrator circuit.

To combine the noise power, square the noise density and integrate. You'll find the highest octave sets the noise density.

Comment: I can't @analogsystemsrf understand your thougths. Can you give me a better explanation?